# Send an email with a HTML file as body (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I set the MailMessage's  body with a HTML file ?

Comment: Here's [a simple example](http://www.example-code.com/csharp/SimpleSendHtmlEmail.asp). And [here's one that includes an embedded image](http://www.example-code.com/csharp/HtmlEmbeddedImage.asp) (as opposed to an `img` link to a web source, which many email clients won't display). Edit: You can of course read the html file with `File.ReadAllText`, which you'd use as in the links.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Just set the [MailMessage.BodyFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.mailmessage.bodyformat.aspx) property to [MailFormat.Html](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.mailformat.aspx), and then dump the contents of your html file to the [MailMessage.Body](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.body.aspx) property:

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(htmlFilePath)) // Path to your 
{                                                         // HTML file
    MailMessage myMail = new MailMessage();
    myMail.From = "from@microsoft.com";
    myMail.To = "to@microsoft.com";
    myMail.Subject = "HTML Message";
    myMail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;

    myMail.Body = reader.ReadToEnd();  // Load the content from your file...
    //...
}
```

Comment: So, just to specify, this answer corresponds with `System.Web.Mail.MailMessage`. When attempting to set the `BodyFormat`, I was having issues because Reflector was telling me it wasn't there. Reason being, I was using `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` (in that class, there's a `bool` flag called `IsBodyHtml` that you can set instead). Also, seems that if all things being equal, `System.Net.Mail` is suggested for use: http://stackoverflow.com/q/64599/324527

Comment: This has changed now. You should use "myMail.IsBodyHtml = true;"

Comment: What if I want to change the content of the HTML code? For ex: `Dear *value_from_C#_variable*`

Answer (score 27):

I case you are using `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage`, you can use:

```
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

`System.Web.Mail.MailMessage` is obsoleted but if using it: `mail.BodyFormat` works.