# system.web.mail vs system.net.mail

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is the difference between `System.Web.Mail` and `System.Net.Mail`?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? Seriously. if you ask waht is better etc- that is worthy an answer. Going through the classes item by item to find the difference is your homework with your copy of the documentation.

Comment: system.net.mail came in with 2.0, so system.web.mail is the only option if you are using less than 2.0

Comment: this stack-overflow thread may helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64599/net-system-web-mail-vs-system-net-mail

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- `System.Web.Mail` was in .NET Framework v1.1
- `System.Net.Mail` is in .NET Framework v2.0 onwards

They are both used for the same purpose. If you use `System.Web.Mail` it only shows a warning,  saying this is deprecated. It still works as supposed to.

If you are really using higher version (2.0 or later) of .NET framework, then use System.Net.Mail.

Comment: Any idea if System.Net.Mail implementation is any faster than System.Web.Mail? Are there any other benefits?

Answer (score 12):

First line in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.aspx) for the `System.Web.Mail` namespace:

> The classes in this namespace have been deprecated. Use the System.Net.Mail namespace instead