# Webmail method email sender Name should be displayed

Tags: asp.net, email, razor

```
WebMail.Send(to: "someone@somewhere.com", subject: "email subject", body: "message body, isBodyHtml: false );

WebMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
WebMail.SmtpPort = 587;
WebMail.EnableSsl = true;
WebMail.UserName = "me@mydomain.com";
WebMail.Password = "the password";
WebMail.From = "me@mydomain.com";
```

By using the above method, I am receiving email from sender name as "me@mydomain.com".. I tried changing the parameters "userName" and "From", but the gmail server rejects the message.

What parameter to add to receive email from a sender name instead of email id..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

> System.Web.Mail is not a full .NET native implementation of the SMTP
>   protocol. Instead, it uses the pre-existing COM functionality in
>   CDONTS. System.Net.Mail, in contrast, is a fully managed
>   implementation of an SMTP client.

So In `MailAddress From = new MailAddress(FromName, FromName);`

```
                                        ^
```

> From =    Gets or sets the e-mail address of the sender

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64599/net-system-web-mail-vs-system-net-mail)

Comment: Ganesh: Gmail says "authentication failed"

Comment: why you are using `WebMail` you can send mails using `SmtpClient`